# Training random forest classifier spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Basically I've cleaned my dataset a little bit, removed headers, bad values etc.. I'm now trying to train a random forest classifier on it so it can make predictions. I've got so far:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.{RandomForestClassificationModel, RandomForestClassifier}
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScaler

object{
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //setting spark context
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Churn")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    //loading and mapping data into RDD
    val csv = sc.textFile("file://filename.csv")
    val data = csv.map {line =>
    val parts = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
    val stringvec = Array(parts(1)) ++ parts.slice(4,20)
    val label = parts(20.toDouble)
    val vec = stringvec.map(_.toDouble)
    LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.dense(vec))
    }
    val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7,0.3))
    val(training, testing) = (splits(0),splits(1))
    val model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(training)
    }
}
```

but I get an error as follows:

```
error: overloaded method value trainClassifier with alternatives:

  (input: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint],strategy: org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.configuration.Strategy,numTrees: Int,featureSubsetStrategy: String,seed: Int)org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint])
   val model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(training)
```

Googling it has gotten me nowhere. I would appreciate it if you can explain what this error is and why I get it. I can then work on a solution on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing enough arguments to `RandomForest.trainClassifier()`, there is no method `trainClassifier(RDD[LabeledPoint])`. There are several overloaded version but you can find the simples version here [trainClassifier](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/RandomForest.scala#L280).

You have to send not only the labeled points but also a `Strategy`, number of trees, `featureSubsetStrategy` and a seed (int).

Example would look like this:

```
RandomForest.trainClassifier(training,
  Strategy.defaultStrategy("Classification"), 
  3, 
  "auto", 
  12345)
```

In practice you would use more trees than 3 and a different seed.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there are no defaults? Like, if I don't set a parameter, it just doesn't pass anything, unlike scikit-learn's implementation?

Comment: nope, no defaults. Scala does allow default parameter values, just the implementers decided not to use them.

Answer (score 0):

[Full answer in Github](https://github.com/ashanchameera/Random_Forest_Regression_2.2.0)[Original Dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/auto+mpg)

Do these things one by one
use two lines inside test data .csv file first line gets as header and the second line gets as test data

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{LabeledPoint, VectorIndexer}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.{RandomForestRegressionModel, 
RandomForestRegressor}


object RandomForest {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     val sparkSess = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("car_mpg").getOrCreate()
     import sparkSess.implicits._
     val carData = sparkSess.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("InterScema","true")
  .csv("D:\\testData\\mpg.csv").toDF("mpg","cylinders","displacement","hp","weight","acceleration","model_year","origin","car_name")
  .map(data => LabeledPoint(data(0).toString.toDouble, Vectors.dense(Array(data(1).toString.toDouble,
    data(2).toString.toDouble, data(3).toString.toDouble, data(4).toString.toDouble, data(5).toString.toDouble))))

val carData_df = carData.toDF("label","features")

val featureIndexer = new VectorIndexer()
  .setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("indexedFeatures").fit(carData)

val Array(training) = carData_df.randomSplit(Array(0.7))

val randomReg = new RandomForestRegressor()
    .setLabelCol("label").setFeaturesCol("features")

val model = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(featureIndexer,randomReg)).fit(training)

val testData = sparkSess.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("InterScema","true")
  .csv("D:\\testData\\testData.csv")
  .toDF("mpg","cylinders","displacement","hp","weight","acceleration","model_year","origin","car_name")
  .map(data => LabeledPoint(data(0).toString.toDouble,
    Vectors.dense(data(1).toString.toDouble,data(2).toString.toDouble,
      data(3).toString.toDouble, data(4).toString.toDouble, data(5).toString.toDouble)))

val predictions = model.transform(testData)
predictions.select("prediction","Label","Features").show()

val rmse = new RegressionEvaluator().setLabelCol("label")
  .setPredictionCol("prediction").setMetricName("rmse").evaluate(predictions)
println("Root Mean Squared Error :\n" + rmse)

val treeModels = model.stages(1).asInstanceOf[RandomForestRegressionModel]
println("Learned Regression tree models :\n" + treeModels.toDebugString)

sparkSess.stop()
```

}
}

[enter link description here](https://github.com/ashanchameera/Random_Forest_Regression_2.2.0)